# MX record for one domain so that other domain can send with the same from

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, postfix, email-server, mx-record

I have two domains: `d1.tld` and `d2.tld`.

I would like to send emails from `d2.tld` with the mail from `user@d1.tld`

**How should I set my `MX record` so that receiving mail servers will accept the message?**

Is it:

`d1.tld IN MX 10 mail.d2.tld`

or

`d2.tld IN MX 10 mail.d1.tld` ?

At the same time I only want to receive emails on `d1.tld` when sent to an `@d1.tld` address - so I guess `d1.tld` should point at `mail.d1.tld` like this `d1.tld IN MX 10 mail.d1.tld`, right?

*Side note: I set an `SPF` record that allows `d2.tld` to send messages with the mail from `@d1.tld`*

Comment: Neither of those mx records are needed. The spf record will potentially help, and won't hinder what you are trying to do. Have you tried it yet? Do you have access to the server you want to send mail from (d2.tld)? Do you have access to mail.d1.tld?

Comment: yes have access to both servers

Answer (score 2):

If you only want mail.d1.tld to receive mail for the d1.tld domain, you only want 1 MX record of:

d1.tld IN MX 10 mail.d1.tld

having a SPF record for d1.tld that allows mail to be sent from mail.d2.tld should be ok.

Not sure where you want d2.tld emails to go, if anywhere?

mail.d2.tld would need to allow relaying for emails not being sent to its own domain name. You can normally do this by setting up IP ranges/subnets in the mail server config. Just make sure you dont configure it as a open relay if its open to the internet.

(Note: no MX record is really needed for someone to receive an email from your domain, but without it, NDR's, auto replies, etc, wont work. Spam filters may also check to make sure MX records exist).

Comment: `d2.tld` isn't supposed to receive any mails. That's why I set the `MAIL FROM` to `@d1.tld`. So you are saying I should set two records: 1. `d1.tld IN MX 10 mail.d1.tld` to receive the returning emails on `d1.tld` and 2. `d2.tld IN MX 10 mail.d2.tld` so that spam filters could find a matching `MX record` for `d2.tld` ? So spam filters won't bother that the `MX record` for `d2.tld` isn't pointing to `d1.tld` ?

Comment: SPAM filters are not only going to check if the MX exists, many of them also are going to check if the MX actually points to the same IP you are trying to send mail from. SPF is [only implemented on a minority of domains](http://spf-all.com/stats.html) and not every SPAM filter setup is using it for validation.

Comment: @syneticon-dj So what record should I set to avoid spam filters?

Comment: @syneticon-dj Are you saying I should set the `MX record` of `d2.tld` to `d1.tld` ? So `d2.tld IN MX 10 mail.d1.tld` ?

Comment: @syneticon-dj And then should I put an `A record` on `mail.d1.tld` that points to the IP of `d1.tld` ?

Comment: If you dont want d2.tld emails to go anywhere, dont put a MX record in for that domain at all. I would say most spam filters wont check the IP of the server sending the mail to the MX record, but there could very well be some spam filters which may reject it. Or they might just attribute that to a spam score, but a fairly minor one. There are many cases where a mail server that is sending the email, isnt actually what the the MX record points to.

Comment: What about the version I suggested before? `d1.tld IN MX 10 mail.d1.tld`, `d2.tld IN MX 10 mail.d1.tld` and `mail.d1.tld IN A 123.456.789.0` ?

Comment: that would be correct if you had two domains that you were sending emails as ([at]d2.tld and [at]d1.tld), and mail.d1.tld would receive both of those emails. Since you want d2.tld to send emails as [at]d1.tld, you only need the d1.tld MX record. if you want [at]d2.tld emails to go somewhere too, you need to add that mx record too, pointing to whatever server is set to receive emails destined for that domain name. if that is being handled by mail.d1.tld, then what you pasted above is ok.

Answer (score 2):

The "proper" kind of setup here would be to set up `mail.d1.tld` in a way that would allow hosts from `d2.tld` sending through it with the envelope address of `d1.tld`. Anything else would either present an overly complex configuration or result in your mail being caught in SPAM filters.

Your RR `d1.tld IN MX 10 mail.d1.tld` would direct mail to d1.tld to the host `mail.d1.tld`. Note, that `mail.d1.tld` has to be an A-RR, it [must not be a CNAME](http://email-museum.com/2008/09/08/why-you-shouldnt-mix-cname-and-mx/).

Comment: What about this version? `d1.tld IN MX 10 mail.d1.tld`, `d2.tld IN MX 10 mail.d1.tld` and `mail.d1.tld IN A 123.456.789.0` ?

Comment: @horen should `mail.d1.tld` handle the mail for `d2.tld` as well? If you do not need mail for `d2.tld`, you don't need an MX RR for it either.